# AngularJs - keeps getting old value of scope even if it is updated

Tags: angularjs

In my application, I'm retrieving some fields from the database and setting the values in local storage when a user logs in.

and then retrieving from local storage to display it to user:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('a') != undefined) {
            $rootScope.a = localStorage.getItem('a');
    }
```

So this is working fine. But the problem is when the value gets updated in the database and user logs in after logging out, then even if the local storage has correct value (i.e., recently updated value), the first time it will display the old value of the scope variable which just got updated.

I tried `$apply()` and also `$digest()` as suggested in different posts here :

```
$timeout( function () {
        $scope.$apply( function () {
            $rootScope.a = localStorage.getItem('a');
        });
    });
```

But it didn't work out. It always displays the old value of scope.
It will only display the new value after reloading the page once.

P.S. - The web page in my application won't be reloaded in any module, even when logging in and out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try watching for the scope variable like this:

```
$rootScope.$watch('a', function (newVal, oldVal){
 if newVal != oldVal
   $rootScope.a = newVal;
}
```

Something else to try is to change 'a' from string to object as I think that angular watches for values using object reference.

here's some useful reference for $watch

http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/watch

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm

Hope it helps in any way

**EDIT**

ok I tested it. You don't need watch neither $apply if you refresh the scope when data refreshing.

Here's what I've done:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myapp', []).controller('myctrl', [
    '$scope', function($scope) {
      var data, getDataFromLocalStorage;
      console.log("scope is ", $scope);
      getDataFromLocalStorage = function() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
      };
      data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "test1"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          text: "test2"
        }, {
          id: 3,
          text: "test3"
        }
      ];
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
      $scope.myData = getDataFromLocalStorage();
      return $scope.changeData = function() {
        var dataNew;
        dataNew = [
          {
            id: 4,
            text: 'text4'
          }, {
            id: 5,
            text: 'text5'
          }, {
            id: 6,
            text: 'text6'
          }
        ];
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(dataNew));
        return $scope.myData = getDataFromLocalStorage();
      };
    }
  ]);

}).call(this);
```

https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/rzvGGx?editors=1010

Comment: should I remove `$apply` ?

Comment: I never use apply. Watch already runs it, so to answer your question yes, I don't think you need it.
Basically using an object and watching it should do the trick, as this is usually what I do

Comment: [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) you have a nice tutorial regarding `$watch`, `$apply` and `$digest`

Comment: So I have to clear the local storage while logging out, right?

Comment: it would be better, yes. You logout,. clear the storage (maybe save the data in the DB if you need to) and then when the new user logs back in you retrive the data and update the scope. Keep data saved when a user is logged out I don't think is best practice for security anyway

Comment: If it helped can you select the answer? Thanks